# Faster (than scipy) calculation of a Chi Square CDF in python

Tags: performance, python-2.7, numpy, scipy

I have FIVE large standard normal distributed vectors (len = 125,000,000) piled up in a [5,125000000] numpy array called vec. I proceed to do:

```
chisqr = sum(multiply(vec,vec)/var_vec,0)
```

And then use scipy to obtain the CDF and do:

```
one_minus_cdf = 1-stats.chi2.cdf(chisqr,[5])
```

Which works fine except this last line takes a large amount of time to complete. Can anyone help me devise a way to make this faster? Thank you in advance.

I'm not very experienced with python so bear with me. I installed numpy and scipy using the unofficial windows binaries ( yes, I'm sorry; I'm on windows). I think by default numpy is compiled against ATLAS? I don't know how to use MKL if I downloaded it. I know I can get a 30 day trial. I just wanted to know if there were some other advice or tricks I could use before diving into using something like MKL (by the way what would be the softest way to start out with this?).

Here is a reproducible example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

vec = np.random.rand(5,12500000)

var_mad = np.tile(np.mat(1).T,(1,12500000))    
chisqr = sum(np.multiply(vec,vec)/var_mad,0)
one_minus_cdf = 1-stats.chi2.cdf(chisqr,[5])
```

Comment: What is `var_vec` and where did `sum` and `multiply` come from? Numpy? A copy/pastable example (don't need all 125M rows) would really help. Last question: how did you install numpy/scipy? Are they optimized with BLAS/ATLAS/MKL/etc?

Comment: What is a large amount of time?  Is the machine swapping?  In the end you are doing a LOT of calculations so it should take awhile.  The chisq cdf is the incomplete gamma function so you could use scipy.special.gammainc() directly.  On my machine this only gives about a 10% speedup.

Comment: What do you think `one_minus_cdf` holds, and what do you want to use it for? You have 5 large vectors of normal samples. You normalize them, square them and add them together, so your result should be distributed as a chi-squared with 5 degrees of freedom. Making 125e6 calls to cdf is going to be slow, but you could estimate the CDF by sorting the chi-squared samples and calling `np.cumsum` on them...

Comment: @Jaime, that sounds very interesting. Could you detail it a bit please?

Comment: @JEquihua Forget it, it's actually slower than calling `chi2.cdf`...

Comment: It's unlikely you can compute the CDF much faster than Scipy does. The call goes directly to a routine written in C that computes the incomplete gamma function, and all time is spent there. MKL et al. are no help --- they do not have incomplete gamma function. Optimizing the C routine for vectorized floating point operations or better incbeta approximations may be possible, but that's easier said than done and large speedups seem unlikely.

Comment: @Craig J copi. Could you provide the code you used to test the calculation using the incomplete gamma just out of curiosity?

Comment: @JEquihua The chi2.cdf is just gamma(k/2,chisq/2) so in this case replace stats.chi2.cdf(chisqr,[5]) with scipy.special.gammainc(2.5,chisqr/2).  As I said, I see a very small speedup between these two calls.  I'm not sure why there is any difference.

Comment: @CraigJCopi  stats.chi2.cdf does quite a bit of checking that the inputs are valid and needs to create intermediate arrays, and checks for broadcasting of arguments. If you are sure you only have valid values, then `stats.chi2._cdf` avoids this overhead.

Comment: Also, If you want values in the upper tail, then you should use the `sf` method instead of `1 - cdf`, it's often more precise and might be a bit faster.

Comment: Thank you very much @user333700 I assume at the end you wanted to write "then gammainc() avoids this overhead"? because the claim is that gamma is a tad faster. Which is the sf method? I have not seen it... By the way, how did you learn about this? I tried to read the code of these functions in Scipy but didn't really find "it". Can I get some advice on this? Where do I find the c code?

Comment: @JEquihua no I meant `._cdf` https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/stats/distributions.py#L2863  `sf` is the method for the "survival function" or complementary cdf, `sf = 1-cdf`. The best place to ask about details of the scipy.stats.distribution implementation is the scipy-user mailing list.